# object generator functions, 'this' and closed upon variable act the same

Tags: javascript

Really trying to nail down closures / OOP concepts in Javascript. Any help is appreciated. Output is via Chrome console.

Both functions build and return an object. The methods in `objMaker()` use 'this' whereas the methods in `staticMaker()` uses the closed upon 'obj' object. Curiously, there is no difference in outcome.

Especially, I would think that directly assigning a value to a property of an object returned by `staticMaker()` would not be reflected by the `.showXY()` method, since that method refers to a closure and not to the returned object.

```
function objMaker(x, y) {
    var obj = {};

    obj.x = x;
    obj.y = y;

    obj.showXY = function() {
        console.log("x: " + this.x + " y: " + this.y);
    }

    obj.changeXY = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    return obj;
}

function staticMaker(x, y) {

    var obj = {};

    obj.x = x;
    obj.y = y;

    obj.showXY = function() {
        console.log("x: " + obj.x + " y: " + obj.y);
    }

    obj.changeXY = function(x, y) {
        obj.x = x;
        obj.y = y;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

**objMaker()** test, using *this*:

```
var objMade = objMaker(100, 200);       
console.log(objMade);                   // Object {x: 100, y: 200}
objMade.showXY();                       // x: 100 y: 200
objMade.changeXY(11, 21);   
objMade.showXY();                       // x: 11 y: 21
objMade.x = "blah"; 
objMade.showXY();                       // x: blah y: 21
console.log(objMade);                   // Object {x: "blah", y: 21}
```

**objMaker()** test, using *obj*:

```
var staticMade = staticMaker(100, 200);         
console.log(staticMade);                // Object {x: 100, y: 200}
staticMade.showXY();                    // x: 100 y: 200
staticMade.changeXY(11, 21);
staticMade.showXY();                    // x: 11 y: 21
staticMade.x = "blah";
staticMade.showXY();                    // x: blah y: 21, expected x: 11 y: 21
console.log(staticMade);                // Object {x: "blah", y: 21}
```

thanks again

Comment: Btw, these functions are called "(object) *factories*", not "object generators"

Comment: "*I would think that directly assigning a value to a property of an object returned by `staticMaker()` would not be reflected by the `.showXY()` method*" - no, the closure refers to the object, not to property values. Changing the object properties will still be reflected. You'd need to close over variables `x` and `y`.